# Swift sorting on arbitrary types

Tags: swift, generics

I have a Set of instances of type `Thingie`, and I want to provide arrays of Thingies sorted on any property of Thingie. Some of the properties are Int, for instance, while others are String, and there could be others. So I wanted to create a sort routine that accepts a string as the name of the property and compares the two properties of two thingies to determine the order.

It seemed like a job for generics, and I'm getting close, but there's a hole.

Here's where I'm at right now:

```
func compare<T:Comparable>(lft: T, _ rgt: T) -> Bool {
    return lft < rgt
}

func orderBy(sortField: String) -> [Thingie] {
    let allArray = (self.thingies as NSSet).allObjects as! [Thingie]

    //typealias T = the type of allArray[0][sortField]
    // or maybe create an alias that conforms to a protocol:
    //typealias T:Comparable = ?

    return allArray.sort({(a, b) -> Bool in
        return self.compare(a[sortField] as! T, b[sortField] as! T)
    })
}
```

I created a compare function using generics, and invoke it in my sort routine. The catch is that `AnyObject!` will not work for my generic, so I need to cast the values returned from `a[sortField]` and `b[sortField]` to be of the same type. It doesn't even really matter what type as long as the compiler is happy that both values are of the same type and that it implements the `Comparable` protocol.

I figured a typealias would do the trick, but maybe there's a better way?

Side question: surely there's a better way to create the initial, unsorted array from the set without resorting to NSSet. A little hint would be welcome. [Solved that bit! Thanks, Oliver Atkinson!]

Here's a big 'ol chunk of code you can paste into a playground. It has three attempts at the orderBy implementation, each with a problem.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

class Thingie: Hashable {
    var data: [String: AnyObject]
    var hashValue: Int

    init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.data = data
        self.hashValue = (data["id"])!.hashValue
    }

    subscript(propName: String) -> AnyObject! {
        return self.data[propName]
    }

}

func ==(lhs: Thingie, rhs: Thingie) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}


var thingies: Set = Set<Thingie>()
thingies.insert(Thingie(data: ["id": 2, "description": "two"]));
thingies.insert(Thingie(data: ["id": 11, "description": "eleven"]));


// attempt 1
// won't compile because '<' won't work when type is ambiguous e.g., AnyObject
func orderByField1(sortField: String) -> [Thingie] {
    return thingies.sort { $0[sortField] < $1[sortField] }
}




// compare function that promises the compiler that the operands for < will be of the same type:
func compare<T:Comparable>(lft: T, _ rgt: T) -> Bool {
    return lft < rgt
}


// attempt 2
// This compiles but will bomb at runtime if Thingie[sortField] is not a string
func orderByField2(sortField: String) -> [Thingie] {
    return thingies.sort { compare($0[sortField] as! String, $1[sortField] as! String) }
}


// attempt 3
// Something like this would be ideal, but protocol Comparable can't be used like this.
// I suspect the underlying reason that Comparable can't be used as a type is the same thing preventing me from making this work.
func orderByField3(sortField: String) -> [Thingie] {
    return thingies.sort { compare($0[sortField] as! Comparable, $1[sortField] as! Comparable) }
}



// tests - can't run until a compiling candidate is written, of course

// should return array with thingie id=2 first:
var thingieList: Array = orderByField2("id");
print(thingieList[0]["id"])

// should return array with thingie id=11 first:
var thingieList2: Array = orderByField2("description");
print(thingieList2[0]["id"])
```

Comment: So, you have a bunch of objects in a Set and you want to create a sorted Array from the set?

Comment: Correct, and I want to specify the property to sort on at runtime.

Comment: I hate to suggest this, but this sort of thing is built right into Objective-C via NSSortDescriptor and key-value coding, so if you just make Thingie an NSObject derivative the whole solution will fall right into your lap. — Yes, I'm sure you'd like a Swift-only solution but sometimes it is best just to solve the problem and move on. :)

Comment: That's probably sound advice. I just have this feeling that if I can do this Swift-ly I'll level up and unlock some cool ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer, though it works, does not make the most of the Swift's excellent type checker. It also switches between the types that can be used in one centralised place which limits extensibility to the framework owner.

The following approach solves these issues. (Please forgive me for not having the heart to delete my previous answer; let us say that it's limitations are instructive...)

As before, we'll start with the target API:

```
struct Thing : ThingType {

    let properties: [String:Sortable]

    subscript(key: String) -> Sortable? {
        return properties[key]
    }
}

let data: [[String:Sortable]] = [
    ["id": 1, "description": "one"],
    ["id": 2, "description": "two"],
    ["id": 3, "description": "three"],
    ["id": 4, "description": "four"],
    ["id": 4, "description": "four"]
]

var things = data.map(Thing.init)

things.sortInPlaceBy("id")

things
    .map{ $0["id"]! } // [1, 2, 3, 4]

things.sortInPlaceBy("description")

things
    .map{ $0["description"]! } // ["four", "one", "three", "two"]
```

To make this possible we must have this `ThingType` protocol and an extension to mutable collections (which will work for sets as well as arrays):

```
protocol ThingType {
    subscript(_: String) -> Sortable? { get }
}

extension MutableCollectionType
where Index : RandomAccessIndexType, Generator.Element : ThingType
{
    mutating func sortInPlaceBy(key: String, ascending: Bool = true) {
        sortInPlace {
            guard let lhs = $0[key], let rhs = $1[key] else {
                return false // TODO: nil handling
            }
            guard let b = (try? lhs.isOrderedBefore(rhs, ascending: ascending)) else {
                return false // TODO: handle SortableError
            }
            return b
        }
    }
}
```

Evidently, the whole idea revolves around this `Sortable` protocol:

```
protocol Sortable {
    func isOrderedBefore(_: Sortable, ascending: Bool) throws -> Bool
}
```

... which can be conformed to independently by any type we want to work with:

```
import Foundation

extension NSNumber : Sortable {
    func isOrderedBefore(other: Sortable, ascending: Bool) throws -> Bool {
        try throwIfTypeNotEqualTo(other)
        let f: (Double, Double) -> Bool = ascending ? (<) : (>)
        return f(doubleValue, (other as! NSNumber).doubleValue)
    }
}

extension NSString : Sortable {
    func isOrderedBefore(other: Sortable, ascending: Bool) throws -> Bool {
        try throwIfTypeNotEqualTo(other)
        let f: (String, String) -> Bool = ascending ? (<) : (>)
        return f(self as String, other as! String)
    }
}

// TODO: make more types Sortable (including those that do not conform to NSObject or even AnyObject)!
```

This `throwIfTypeNotEqualTo` method is just a convenience extension of `Sortable`:

```
enum SortableError : ErrorType {
    case TypesNotEqual
}

extension Sortable {
    func throwIfTypeNotEqualTo(other: Sortable) throws {
        guard other.dynamicType == self.dynamicType else {
            throw SortableError.TypesNotEqual
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it. Now we can conform new types to `Sortable` even outside of the framework and the type checker is validating our `[[String:Sortable]]` source data at compile time. Also, if `Thing` is extended to conform to `Hashable` then `Set<Thing>` will also be sortable by key...

Note that, although `Sortable` is itself unconstrained (which is awesome), source `data` and `Thing`'s `properties` can be constrained to dictionaries with `NSObject` or `AnyObject` values if required by making use of a protocol like:

```
protocol SortableNSObjectType : Sortable, NSObjectProtocol { }
```

... or more directly by declaring `data` and `Thing`'s `properties` as:

```
let _: [String : protocol<Sortable, NSObjectProtocol>]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the implementation of `Thingie` but maybe you could provide more context.

You could however go for something like this

```
func orderBy(sortField: String) -> [Thingie] {
  return thingies.allObjects.map { $0 as! Thingie }.sort { $0[sortField] < $1[sortField] }
}
```

If you could provide a playground example so I can provide further help.

Also why did you use NSSet rather than a swift Set? would that give you what you want

```
let thingies: Set = Set<Thingie>()

func orderBy(sortField: String) -> [Thingie] {
  return thingies.sort { $0[sortField] < $1[sortField] }
}
```

**edit:**

The trouble is with swift's type safety - it requires you to know what types you are dealing with so that it can compile correctly - if you specify the actual type when you want to order the field you can get it to work as expected.

```
func orderByField<T: Comparable>(sortField: String, type: T.Type) -> [Thingie] {
  return thingies.sort { ($0[sortField] as? T) < ($1[sortField] as? T) }
}

var thingieList: Array = orderByField("id", type: Int.self);
print(thingieList[0]["id"])

var thingieList2: Array = orderByField("description", type: String.self);
print(thingieList2[0]["id"])
```

The above will print 2 then 11 - if you wanted to get around this you could store your objects in a different struct and then you can sort the array of 'Things' on the variable.

e.g.

```
struct Thing {

  let id: Int
  let description: String

}

var data: [Thing] = [
  Thing(id: 2, description: "two"),
  Thing(id: 11, description: "eleven")
]

let first  = data.sort { $0.id < $1.id }.first?.id
let second = data.sort { $0.description < $1.description }.first?.id

print(first)
print(second)
```

Which would achieve the same thing - 2 and 11

I would advise against using AnyObject where possible as its trying to cheat the compiler into telling it you don't care for its help.

Its an interesting problem though and I hope this helps you towards your solution.

Comment: Thingies is a Swift set - I had missed that it had a sort function, and couldn't find a way to get the elements out of the Set and into an Array without casting to an NSSet first. So that does simplify things. The catch is that $0[sortField] < $1[sortField] doesn't compile. Error is `Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'AnyObject! ' operands`

Comment: Can you make a playground showing this example please

Comment: I'll figure out how to share a playground with you all after work tonight. Thanks very much for your help so far.

Comment: I have added code to the post above that can be plopped into a playground.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I was able to use `Comparable` as a data type, I would be home free, but although many protocols can be uses as (non-generic) types, Comparable can't, and I suspect the underlying reason for that is related to why I'm not able to do what I want. Making `Thing` a `struct ` with typed elements begs the question how to specify the sort criterion programatically. Your attention to this problem has been very helpful to me though, so thanks once more.

Answer (score 1):

I will start with the target API (ignoring conformance to `Hashable` as its addition wont change anything in what follows). So, let's say we'd like to be able to write the following:

```
var thingies = [
    ["id": 1, "description": "one"],
    ["id": 2, "description": "two"],
    ["id": 3, "description": "three"],
    ["id": 4, "description": "four"]
].map(Thingie.init)

thingies.sortInPlace{ $0["id"] < $1["id"] }
```

... and even:

```
thingies.sortInPlaceBy("id")

thingies
    .map{ $0["id"]!.value } // [1, 2, 3, 4]

thingies.sortInPlaceBy("description")

thingies
    .map{ $0["description"]!.value } // ["four", "one", "three", "two"]
```

Obviously, we'd need an extension of `MutableCollectionType` protocol along the lines of:

```
protocol ThingieDatumSubscriptable {
    subscript(_: String) -> ThingieDatum? { get }
}

extension Thingie : ThingieDatumSubscriptable {}

extension MutableCollectionType
where Index : RandomAccessIndexType, Generator.Element : ThingieDatumSubscriptable
{
    mutating func sortInPlaceBy(datumName: String, ascending: Bool = true) {
        let f: (ThingieDatum?, ThingieDatum?) -> Bool = ascending ? (<) : (>)
        sortInPlace{ f($0[datumName], $1[datumName]) }
    }
}
```

This `ThingieDatum` would then be something like:

```
import Foundation

struct ThingieDatum : Comparable {
    let type: AnyObject.Type
    let value: AnyObject
    let name: String
    init(keyValuePair: (String, AnyObject)) {
        name = keyValuePair.0
        value = keyValuePair.1
        type = keyValuePair.1.dynamicType
    }
}
```

... and its conformance to `Comparable` implemented in some sort of pedestrian way as follows (unless we introduce more protocols):

```
func == (lhs: ThingieDatum, rhs: ThingieDatum) -> Bool {
    guard lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.type == rhs.type else {
        return false
    }
    switch lhs.type {
    // TODO: implement for other types
    case is NSNumber.Type: return lhs.value as! NSNumber == rhs.value as! NSNumber
    case is NSString.Type: return (lhs.value as! String) == (rhs.value as! String)
    default: break
    }
    return false
}

func < (lhs: ThingieDatum, rhs: ThingieDatum) -> Bool {
    assert(lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.type == rhs.type)
    switch lhs.type {
    // TODO: implement for other types
    case is NSNumber.Type: return (lhs.value as! NSNumber).doubleValue < (rhs.value as! NSNumber).doubleValue
    case is NSString.Type: return (lhs.value as! String) < (rhs.value as! String)
    default: break
    }
    return false
}
```

Armed with such a `ThingieDatum` we can finally work out the `Thingie` itself:

```
struct Thingie {
    var data: [ThingieDatum]

    init(_ data: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.data = data.map(ThingieDatum.init)
    }

    subscript(datumName: String) -> ThingieDatum? {
        for datum in data where datum.name == datumName {
            return datum
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And although this is, of course, all meant as a fun exercise, it does work (copy and paste into the playground if you can work our the correct order of snippets)... To take this idea further, however, we would probably want to constrain `ThingiDatum` initialiser to a custom protocol (rather than `AnyObject`), which would guarantee comparability. We would then conform to that protocol with each type we want to work with instead of `switch`ing through those types in one centralised place...

Comment: up vote now for completeness and structure of the answer; I'll have to study it a bit before I mark it as correct. I had not considered an approach like ThingieDatum, but it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. It was a pleasure juggling marbles over this excellent conundrum...